# Can NSXMLParser access strings or comments in XML files?

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I have an XML file that I have successfully parsed and I know that NSXMLParser uses the functions listed below but is it possible to search by strings instead of element tags?  I want to find the string that is commented out at the bottom of my XML file.  Is there anyway to access that commented out string with NSXMLParser?

XML CODE

```
<audioTracks>0</audioTracks>
<!--7934fad5a3a -->
```

PARSING CODE

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"audioTracks"]) {
    NSLog(@"Element Name: --> %@", elementName);
  }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
  NSLog(@"foundCharacters --> %@", string);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"audioTracks"]) {
    NSLog(@"Element Name: --> %@", elementName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the following delegate method on `NSXMLParserDelegate` to handle comments in the XML file being processed:

[`- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundComment:(NSString *)comment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser:foundComment:)

Comment: This works absolutely perfect.  Thank you so much for the help.